# Injecting code to track events on Delphi

Tags: reflection, introspection, rtti, delphi

I have a big and old application written in Delphi version 2007 for over a decade now and in order to rewrite it I intend to understand which parts/features of it are mostly used by the majority of its users.

The idea that came up is to track objects clicks and window creations to populate a log or analytics tool like Google Analytics or Deskmetrics with quantitative and qualitative data in order to help on the decision making.

To achieve that, I'm trying to figure out what is the easiest path respecting the current version limitations. One of the possibilities I am exploring is understanding how to implement some generic code that could be somehow "injected/reflected" in a class level so all instantiated objects may among other things, call a function passing parameters that identify themselves and this function would then take action to log that info using the best tool.

The only real solution so far is copying and pasting this function call on several thousands of onClick/onCreate methods and I'd like to avoid it while I am open to all other possibilities that may come out on this thread.

Thanks!

Comment: An action manager would let you track all user actions centrally.

Comment: Check out the [AOP demo](https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/dsharp/src/ad7c5983505f0117f1347f92d2bb96c07bdfda94/Samples/AOP/?at=master) from the [Dsharp Library](https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/dsharp/src/ad7c5983505f?at=master).

Comment: Introducing an Action Manager is indeed the correct way to go about this.  Each on-click becomes an action OnExecute.   While you are at it, add some additional logging, so that you can see what the user is actually doing with your app. Be sure not to log private information like patient/customer data into those log files, just what tools/buttons are used.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan In this app there is no Action Manager currently in place. Is there a quick way to use one without having to manually referring each object's actions to it? In the way I see, you must get the button or menu item to associate one by one? Am I wrong? Thanks again!

Comment: You are going to have to do some work to get where you need to be. No magic fix.

Comment: @whosrdaddy I saw the code and tried using the project with Delphi 2007 but looks like there are some dependencies which are not there yet. Do you know if this would be related to other examples on the Dsharp lib and could be removed somehow? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @WarrenP the same issue I asked above to DavidHeffernan applies here. About logging private data, this is definitely not what I want. It's basically tracking of functionalities/features in order to understand how much code I can just not write. Thanks!

Comment: Dsharp is only from D2010 and up

Comment: WRT Action manager, I you truly want to put the action manager on EVERY component that has an on click event, for example, you could do it programatically by iterating through the children of all forms on start up and assigning the action manager to each child that has an on click event. Similarly for OnCreate.

Comment: Doesnt Codesite have a utility that can automatically add a "Enter Mehod" and "Exit Method" to all methods with a single click?